# Scrapy getting the wrong value

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am scraping a website with scrapy and I am getting a wrong value after scraping.

I am pretty sure I am doing it right, however, when I should be getting a value of let's say 59, maybe I am getting 89, and there is no 89, at all, anywhere in the website.

I understand this could be a measure from the website to prevent scraping? Is there a way to bypass this?

EDIT:

I am trying to scrape [This website](https://www.1and1.co.uk/dedicated-server), the field I am having problems with is the price. For example, in the first Server (L4i) the price should be 39 (without the decimals) however, it gets 59 every time I try.

EDIT 2:

This happens for the price on every server. I always get a different value to the one it shows.

EDIT 3:

Based on @rongon answer, this is all the code I have, and still get the wrong value:

```
import scrapy

class OneAndOneServers(scrapy.Spider):
    name =  "servers"
    start_urls = ['https://www.1and1.com/dedicated-server']

    def parse(self, response):

        price = response.xpath('//div[@data-price-article="tariff-ded-server-l-4i"]//span[@class="price-before-separator"]/text()').extract()

        yield {'price': price}
```

EDIT 4:

I am quite stupid. Seriously. Although I was trying to scrap the .co.uk website, in the script I was calling to the .com website. Case closed, my brain farted really big and I am a little blind too.

Comment: Use scrapy shell to fetch the URL and test your code.

Comment: As mentioned above, you may want to use `scrapy shell <url>` for testing. I would also recommend to inspect response (e.g. in Chrome DevTools -> Network) to see if the page even contains the values you want. If not, you will need to find where these values come from (e.g. additional XHR requests).

Comment: Also, you will more likely get help if you share the page you're trying to scrape.

Comment: I just added the website I am trying to scrap and where the error is.

Comment: The prices on that website aren't fixed, they depend on cookies or some other sort of session data or user information.  For example, there's a "Show pricing with VAT" option that turns your 39 into a 47 persistently, without changing the URL.  I didn't see any option that would produce the 59 you're seeing, but perhaps it's quoting you prices in a different currency.  Displaying more of the context to the found value (enough to include the currency symbol, in particular) may give a hint as to what's going on.

Comment: Never mind, see edit 4. It was my fault all along.

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely lies in your xpath/css-extract command.

With the following XPath I am able to extract the price of the L4i without any problems:

```
response.xpath('//div[@data-price-article="tariff-ded-server-l-4i"]//span[@class="price-before-separator"]/text()').extract()
```

If you would post your code, we could probably help you out more.

Comment: I just tried your solution. I keep getting a value of 59 when the value should be 39.

Comment: when you ran that bit, which value did you get? 39 or 59?

Comment: I get 39 correctly. This is really weird. You could check in the shell what the spider sees with `view(response)`, maybe there is some issue.

Comment: I edited my question, as you can see that is the only code I run, and still get 59. I really cannot understand what is going on.